# How can you use css to style all <td> elements in a table when one of the <td> elements has a certain class?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to highlight an entire row of in a table when one of the  elements contains a certain class.  Example:

```css
.whole-row-red-background {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='whole-row-red-background'></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody </table>
```

In the example above, only the first cell (the first td) of the second row in the table is set with a red background.  Under this scenario (first `<td>` in the row has this class) I need **all** `<td>` elements in the row to have a red background.

Comment: Will the first cell in the row always be the cell with the 'whole-row-red-background' class?

Comment: Soon we will be able to do `tr:has(.whole-row-red-background) td` until all browsers support it the only CSS only solution can only work if the class is only on the first td. If it is on any td in the row, it would need JavaScript. Or just change the code that generates this to also add a class to the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the general sibling selector.
More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Here is your updated snippet:

```css
.whole-row-red-background {
  background-color: red;
}

.whole-row-red-background ~ td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='whole-row-red-background'></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody </table>
```

Comment: Works, but only if the first cell in a row has the class. Which is why I asked the OP to clarify if that will always be the case

Answer (score 0):

```js
let td = document.getElementsByClassName("whole-row-red-background")[0]
let tr = td.closest("tr")
tr.style.backgroundColor='red'
```

```css
.whole-row-red-background {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
      <td>z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='whole-row-red-background'>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I don't see a JavaScript tag on the question

Comment: Good answers also include some explanation along with code.